# qDebug()<<qstring no longer compiling

Tags: qt, qdebug

I have built a QWidgets application in Qt 5.3.1 and in some places have used

```
qDebug() << msg;
```

where msg is a QString.
I had had this compiling and running for a few years, but tonight I decided to recompile it and I got the message:

```
D:\devt\myapp\extcoder.cpp:29: error: no matching function for call to 'QMessageLogger::debug()'
 qDebug()<<msg;
        ^
```

In fact I got a similar problem in *another* app I wrote the other day, and by experimenting I thought I had fixed it by replacing such calls by qDebug(msg).
But it looks as if some kind of software rot is setting in!
Any ideas? Of course the file starts with

```
#include <QDebug>
```

To test this problem I built a barebones QWidgets application (of a QMainWindow kind), and the only code I wrote, was (apart from the #include)

```
qDebug()<<"Hello world";
```

in the MainWindow constructor. I get exactly the same compilation error.

Comment: what is your qt version?

Comment: I just edited my text: 5.3.1

Comment: Did you try to re-install Qt?

Answer (score 1):

Reinstallation of Qt made `qDebug()<<s` work again.

It was indeed a kind of "software rot": I reinstalled qt 5.3.1 after making a copy of the original so I could compare the new with the old.

Using Winmerge I was able to uncover the error:
I dont know exactly how it happened but the file qlogging.h got corrupted.
Here's what happened: at lines 118 and 120 the declarations of two versions of debug got rewritten to NBIS_debug.
Now I have worked trying to port free software from the NBIS. At some stage I must have renamed a debug function from debug to NBIS_debug, and this modification must have been propagated all the way to qlogging.h.

Comment: I had this error happen on our Jenkins, and my machine? how could have qlogging.h got corrupted on multiple machine? :(

Answer (score 0):

[QDebug &QDebug::operator<<(const QString &s)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdebug.html#operator-lt-lt-16) is supported in Qt.

Output example:

```
QString s;

s = "a";
qDebug().noquote() << s;    // prints: a
qDebug() << s;              // prints: "a"
```

Your Qt environment must be broken. Please, check your environment and re-install Qt if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I had to reinstall Ubuntu and Qt. The reinstall only Qt did not help.